# How can I overlay a control on a window?

Tags: wpf

Right now I have a normal window with a bunch of controls.

When the user hits a certain button I want to dim the entire window and then display a popup on top of it. Not a true dialog box, just something that is inside the window.

So this is my theory...

1. Every control is on layer 0.
2. There is a rectangle the same size as the form in layer 1. This has 50% transparency.
3. My popup is loaded into layer 2.
4. Clicking anywhere on the rectangle will do the same thing as pressing close on the pop-up.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is perfectly possible.

Put your entire UI in any panel inside of a `<Grid>`.

Then, in the same grid, put a `<Rectangle Opacity=".5" Visibility="Collapsed" />` for the overlay and a centered panel for the popup.

Handle the rectangle's click event and hide the popup.

Comment: @SLaks Do I just need to add `<Rectangle Opacity=".5" Visibility="Collapsed" />` as I don't see a Rectangle appear when I change the `Visibility` to `Visible`.  How do I get the rectangle to fill the entire window?