# How to overlay WPF Control at specific location

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a FlowDocumentPageViewer that I use to display a multi-page document. I want a small control to appear next to certain paragraphs in the document which the user can do certain interactions with the paragraphs. The control should not appear when the paragraphs are not visible.

I have the coordinates of the Point where I want to display it, and have written logic in a page change event handler to check each page for the paragraphs, but how should I display the controls?

Create a Popup? Adorner? A separate window? A Canvas on top of the FlowDocumentPageViewer? Something else?

Answer (score 0):

It might be too late to answer this but for anyone who has encountered the same problem, take a look at this:
[How can I overlay a control on a window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3275759/how-can-i-overlay-a-control-on-a-window)